# "Mail server" on small LAN network

Tags: email, smtp, local-area-network, imap, accounts

What is the best way to go about the following issue?

There are about 7 machines under Win XP Pro, each has its own email client (Outlook 2007) with own accounts (eg. gmail, yahoo etc.)

I want to combine all those accounts under one machine, set up a good spam filter, antivirus and share, preferebly via IMAP, all the incoming emails with other machines. And all the outgoing mail will go through this "main" machine, through one account but with signatures of those who sent it.

With time, there will be no need in all those seperate acounts, as all the replies to all will go to only one main account. But here's more, is there a way to set up a filter, so that only machine to whom the reply was intended will see it and none of the others will or go directly to whom it was intended. And also have the ability for those machines to forward emails to each other via some internal lan accounts.

And of course, looking for OpenSource solution. Thanks to all in advance!!!

Comment: So you want seven people to use the same email address?!

Comment: Why, why, why would you even want to do this crazy thing? Just give everyone their own email address.

Comment: We already have a way to make sure mail goes directly to whom it was intended - it's the part of the email address before the @ sign.

Comment: want to get rid of all those addresses and spam associated with 'em, use one in/out and the rest should feed on it

Comment: No you don't, you really don't.

Comment: Having fewer addresses isn't going to solve a spam problem. Use Spamassasin or something.

Answer (score 5):

> But here's more, is there a way to set up a filter, so that only machine to whom the reply was intended will see it and none of the others will or go directly to whom it was intended. And also have the ability for those machines to forward emails to each other via some internal lan accounts.

No.

Comment: i need a tip on open source software solution to implement this, possibly more than one soft

Answer (score 4):

Go with postfix or Zimbra. And don't do what you're planning. You're nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You need an MTA with a bunch of hacks to do this crazyness. Postfix is the way in my opinion. You can set up a lot of things with it. Just read the documentation.